# My HTML isn't scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll

Sorry that this is a question asked a lot, but y'know it's a bit of a specific instance problem. I can't tell why it isn't scrolling. Here's my code:

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding:20px;background-color:#000033;height:1500px;">
  <div id='stars'></div>
  <div id='stars2'></div>
  <div id='stars3'></div>
  <p style="color: #FFFFFF";><b>TITLE1</b></p>
  <p style="color: #FFFFFF";> PARAGRAPH </p>
  <p style="color: #FFFFFF";><sub>SUBPARAGRAPH</sub>
    <p style="color: #FFFFFF";><sub><sub><sub><sub>V0.81</sub></sub>
      </sub>
    </p>
    <IMG height="1080" width="1920" SRC="bricks.png"><br>
    <IMG height="1080" width="1920" SRC="pink.png"><br>
    <IMG height="1080" width="1920" SRC="black.jpg"><br>

</div>
```

Sorry it's a mishmash. Any suggestions in terms of tidying it up are also appreciated. And the CSS of `stars.css` (http://pastebin.com/nSiiUy1d) is very large.

It's for a purely personal website, I just wanna scroll.

Comment: The link to your stylesheet `stars.css` should be in the `<head>` section and not in the body of the page. You will also need to include the css from this file into your question, since the problem might be in that specific file. There is also alot of errors in the above, for instance this `<p style="color:#FFFFFF";>` should be `<p style="color:#FFFFFF;">` and it would also make more sense to add this rule into your stylesheet instead of inline.

Comment: You don't close the following `<p>` tag `<p style="color:#FFFFFF";><sub>SUBPARAGRAPH</sub>`, change it into `<p style="color:#FFFFFF;"><sub>SUBPARAGRAPH</sub></p>`

Comment: Okay, neat, the style thing worked (to clear it up, not to make it scroll) and I don't know why I didn't see it before. I like how forgiving html is, I never would've noticed not closing that tag.. The css is here: http://pastebin.com/nSiiUy1d (Sorry!)

Comment: @SamScott what's not scrolling? The stars or the page?

Comment: @SamScott I'm a little confused as to what's not scrolling. I converted your code to a Code Snippet and the page is scrollable.

Comment: @hungerstar Sorry for the late reply: The page wasn't scrolling. I took out all of the references to stars, and it scrolls like it should now, so I think I'll copy across the stuff I still want, and maybe leave the fancy stuff until I actually understand what it does and how to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove that 1500px height from the div and you should be able to scroll.
Btw I recommend you not to use fixed widths and heights when coding your style attribute, try to use percentages instead, or event "max-width" if you want to put limits.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, but it was probably one reason why the scrolling isn't working.

Answer (score -1):

In terms of tidying, I recommend reading up on indentation, [here's a decent article on the subject](https://css-tricks.com/what-beautiful-html-code-looks-like/).

Comment: This should be an comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Understood. Thanks @hungerstar.